# How to add caption to thumbnail hover - Bootstrap?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, hover

I am trying to use this thumbnail hover caption plugin for bootstrap.

http://sevenx.de/demo/bootstrap/thumbnail-hover-caption.html

This is the code.

```
<div class="thumbnail">
                <div class="caption" style="display: none;">
                    <h4>Caption Title</h4>
                    <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse" rel="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Preview"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a> <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="" class="btn btn-inverse" data-original-title="Visit Website"><i class="icon-share"></i></a></p>
                </div>
                <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="ALT NAME">
              </div>
```

In this page, there is a part 'SlideIn/Out'.

When you hover on a thumbnail normally it slides in or out. This is what I want.

However, what I also need is when my cursor is not hover on thumbnail, there should be small caption at the bottom which I will write there a tagline.

So basically, default position will be small caption, when my mouse is over thumbnail it will slide in.

This is an exact example what I need. It can be viewed http://www.usatoday.com/news/

**NO HOVER**

[image]

**HOVER**

[image]

This is the jsfiddle page http://jsfiddle.net/g4j8B/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to place another div above the image and style it to your needs.

Then add the hide() or show() according to the Bootstraps sliding etc.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/g4j8B/3/)

HTML:

```
<li class="span3">
                    <div class="thumbnail">
                        <div class="caption">
                             <h4>Caption Title</h4>

                            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt.</p>
                            <p><a href="#" class="btn btn-inverse" rel="tooltip" title="Preview"><i class="icon-eye-open"></i></a>  <a href="#" rel="tooltip" title="Visit Website" class="btn btn-inverse"><i class="icon-share"></i></a>

                            </p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="caption-btm">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing eli...</div>
                        <img src="http://placehold.it/600x400" alt="ALT NAME">
                    </div>
                     <h4>Item Name</h4>

                </li>
```

CSS:

```
.caption-btm{
        background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
        width: 100%;
        height: 30px;
        position: absolute;
        bottom: 4px;
        color: #fff;
    }
```

JQuery:

```
$('#hover-cap-4col .thumbnail').hover(

                function() {
                    $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250);
                    $('.caption-btm').hide(100);
                },

                function() {
                    $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250);
                    $('.caption-btm').show(450);
                });
```

**EDIT**

The above Jquery will show and hide every .caption-btm.

But this will hide the specific one that it's being hovered over:

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/HP53R/)

Jquery:

```
    $('#hover-img .thumbnail').hover(

            function () {
                $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250);
                $(this).find('.caption-btm').hide(250);
            },

            function () {
                $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250);
                $(this).find('.caption-btm').show(250);
            });
```

Comment: When it slides up, the caption appears immediately. Is it possible to show the caption after sliding up finishes? Also is it possible to make background transparent as it is hover.

Comment: It's possible to make the background transparent with rgba. Would you like the bottom caption to slide in as the other one slides up?

Comment: Sure, only the CSS and Jquery has changed. I edited the above.

Comment: I have a simple question rather than coming from the left bottom, can that caption slide from the left to the right?

Comment: You can try use the Bootstrap slide, but they dont have an option from the right or left. See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/g4j8B/6/ that's using the bootstrap slideDown(). If you want it from the side, you are probably going to need to write a custom script where you add or remove a class.

Comment: I have a small problem. If I have 2 thumbnails, they slideup and down at the same time if I move my mouse over a thumbnail. I think I must do something about it. Test in here http://www.carantina.com/test.html

Answer (score 1):

Here is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fnCuC/), check the first item.

What i've done is add some text bedofre the caption and after the thumbnail and tell it to hide when the user hovers on the thumbnail:

```
.thumbnail:hover .front {
    display: none;
}
```

It isn't pretty (it has inline css for the sake of the example), but i think it does what you want.

Comment: As you said it shall be prettier and the bar need to be at the bottom. Beside when I move my cursor from thumbnail, the caption bar appears before waiting the slideout function. It shall be shown after slideout finishes.

Comment: Yes, that you can accomplish by tweaking the slideout animation time, or even animating the hover on the thumbnail with a -webkit-transition.