# Modifying bootstrap thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to modify bootstrap thumbnail hover options, and just to put a color over image with some text. I can't quite figure out and find how to do a basic image hover to change the color OVER the picture and to add some text to it. I really like the transitions in this article https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/css-tricks-for-your-divi-theme-project-and-product-thumbnails

But I can't figure out what CSS to add, etc... Can someone please explain to me the basics of overlaying the image and adding centered text on hover. I know this is very basic stuff, but I really have trouble with it. If help could stick to the following code?

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">
    <div class="thumbnail">
        <img src="images/bg3.jpg">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You might find this SO question helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17828896/how-to-add-caption-to-thumbnail-hover-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

jQuery & CSS will be your best option to accomplish this. I built this really quick, its a simplistic way of accomplishing what your looking for. It should get you started, hope it helps. http://jsfiddle.net/zacnespral21/wke9jg7j/

As for an explanation of how to accomplish this, I suggest reading up on jQuery hover effects, along with CSS hover effects. You can also use jQuery mouseover which would have made the fiddle even simpler and cleaner.

```
$(function() {    

$('something').hover(

    function() {
        $(this).find('.caption').slideDown(250);
        $('.caption-btm').hide();
    },

    function() {
        $(this).find('.caption').slideUp(250);
        $('.caption-btm').show();
    });

$('something').hover(

    function() {
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeIn(250);
    },

    function() {
        $(this).find('.caption').fadeOut(250);
    });    

$('something').hover(

    function() {
        $(this).find('.caption').show();
    },

    function() {
        $(this).find('.caption').hide();
    });
```

});

CSS Hover: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

jQuery Hover: https://api.jquery.com/hover/

jQuery Mouse Over: https://api.jquery.com/mouseover/